# change UITextView height programmatically with the text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, cgrect

i want change the UITextView programmatically with the amount of text i set, and i have a problem, if i add a the UITextView with interface builder and i do this:

```
CGRect frame = textViewA1.frame;
frame.size.height = textViewA1.contentSize.height;
textViewA1.frame = frame;
```

all work fine, but if i create the UITextView programmatically, the height don't change, i do this:

```
 UITextView *textViewA1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 320, 50)];
[textViewA1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Enriqueta" size:15]];
[textViewA1 setScrollEnabled:NO];
[textViewA1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[textViewA1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[textViewA1 setText:@"A lot of text"];
CGRect frame = textViewA1.frame;
frame.size.height = textViewA1.contentSize.height;
textViewA1.frame = frame;
```

in this way the height size of the uitextview don't change, how i can do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think you need to do :

```
CGRect frame = textViewA1.frame;
frame.size.height = textViewA1.contentSize.height;
textViewA1.frame = frame;
```

after the addsubview:

```
[self.view addSubview: self.textView];
```

Answer (score 10):

Just send the `sizeToFit` message to the `UITextView`.  It will adjust its own height to just fit its text.  It will not change its own width or origin.

```
[textViewA1 sizeToFit];
```

Comment: It actually can change the width.  It very much depends on the parent view, and the sizing attributes of the other subviews of the parent.  This is a very "it depends" use case!!!  Good added answer though :-)

Comment: Please describe a scenario (other than using a vertical text layout) where a `UITextView` will change its width in response to `sizeToFit`.  I didn't find one in my testing.

Comment: if the width initially given to the textView is less than that of the parent and there is nothing next to it left or right, it may increase its width to fill the width of the parent.  IF this is NOT correct, and you have proof, I actually would love to see it, as it might simplify portions of code I have :-)  Thanks for any info.

Comment: My test case with a `UITextView` narrower than its parent, and no siblings, doesn't change its width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the frame size for the text you have, for instance:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Enriqueta" size:15];
NSString *text = @"A lot of text";
CGSize frameSize = [text sizeWithFont:font];
CGRect originalFrame = textViewA1.frame;
textViewA1.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(originalFrame), CGRectGetMinY(originalFrame), frameSize.width, frameSize.height);
```

To keep it from exceeding a particular height, use:

```
CGFloat maxHeight = 100; // or something
CGSize frameSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxHeight];
```

Comment: To constrainedSize give me this error: Sending 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') to parameter of incompatible type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize'); , and i have an other question, how i can constrained only with the width?

Comment: Just use a REALLY big number for the height parameter of the constrainedToSize routine.  Give it your known static width, and a really big number for the height.  The method will then return the actual size needed!!!  This fails because that function takes in a CGSize.

Comment: @Piero - To fix your "Sending 'CGFloat' to parameter of incompatible..." error, try this `CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);` instead of `CGFloat maxHeight = 100`.

Comment: @qegal is right, constrainedToSize wants a size, not a float.

Comment: By the way, the parameters above for the code I wrote to create `maxSize` are completely changeable. It was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Enriqueta" size:15];
textViewA1.font = font;
NSString * theText = @"A lot of text";
CGSize theStringSize = [theText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(190, 1000000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGRect frame = textViewA1.frame;
frame.size.height = theStringSize.height;
textViewA1.frame = frame;
```

This of course has a static width of 190 pixels for the textview.  You can obviously change that!!!

Answer (score -2):

to scroll `UITextView` when added multiple line in textview

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect frameTextView = textView.frame;
    frameTextView.height -= KEY_BOARD_HEIGHT;
    textView.frame = frameTextView;
}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
{
    CGRect frameTextView = textView.frame;
    frameTextView.height += KEY_BOARD_HEIGHT;
    textView.frame = frameTextView;
}
```